# How to pass value of a field from Parent Work Item to Child in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, user-stories

I need to write a rule to copy a field's value to child work item(User Story) from parent work item(Epic) in Azure DevOps. But I cannot find a way using Work item's rule settings in Process.

How can I set the field in work item when parent is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in feature can pass value between different work items. The rule only applies to the same work item. For example, we can set a copy rule to copy the value from one filed to another within the same work item.

See [Rules and rule evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-reference?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance) and [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) for details.

The only way I can think of is writing a script by calling the [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API to get the value of the filed from parent work item, then calling the [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API to update the child work item. Then setup a trigger to run the scripts once the parent work item is updated.

Comment: Thank you for help, I thought about using REST API too. I thought, maybe there is a built-in way I did not know it. So, I begin to find a way using REST API.